# How to set start slide for views slideshow jcarousel

Tags: 7, views

I am using viewsslideshow and viewsslideshowjcarousel modules. I am displaying image thumbnail as jcarousel bottom of the Gallery slides using viewsslideshowjcarousel module. It's working perfectly.

Here is the problem. I would like to navigate to slide directly using the URL. Views slide show support this by passing #unique-id:slidenumber as discussed [here](http://drupal.org/node/1266794). But, i can not able to slide automatically to the the thumbnail of the jcarosel pager that image belongs to. I see setting start option as discussed in [Documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) should do the job. But adding that is breaking the carousel in below code inside views_slideshow_jcarousel.js file.

```
// Add views slieshow api calls for views slideshow jCarousel pager.
Drupal.behaviors.viewsSlideshowJcarouselPager = { 
  attach: function (context) {
    // Process pause on hover.
    $('.views_slideshow_jcarousel_pager:not(.views-slideshow-jcarousel-pager-processed)', context).addClass('views-slideshow-jcarousel-pager-processed').each(function() {
      // Parse out the unique id from the full id.
      var pagerInfo = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
      var location = pagerInfo[2];
      pagerInfo.splice(0, 3);
      var uniqueID = pagerInfo.join('_');
      $(this).jcarousel({        
        vertical: parseInt(Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location].orientation),
        scroll: parseInt(Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location].scroll),
        visible: parseInt(Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location].visible),
        wrap: Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location].wrap,
        animation: (isNaN(Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location].animation)) ? Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location].animation : parseInt(Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location].animation),
        initCallback: function(carousel) {
          Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowJCarouselPager[uniqueID][location]['carouselObj'] = carousel;
        }
      });

      $(this).find('.views_slideshow_jcarousel_pager_item').each(function(index, pagerItem) {
        $(pagerItem).click(function() {
          Drupal.viewsSlideshow.action({ "action": 'goToSlide', "slideshowID": uniqueID, "slideNum": index });
        });
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Any idea how to start jcarosuel based on the slidenum passed in the url ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a contextual filter to the view that sorts the results putting the desired element in the first position of the carousel.

There is a nice reference for that: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views